# Why is my loop acting the opposite of how it's supposed to, based on the user input?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Here is what is meant to happen: After the user is prompted with, "Would you like to enter another name?" if the user enters 'Y' they should be prompted to add another name. Instead, the program runs the loop that starts after cin << response, which I thought I set the condition to only run if the user doesn't enter 'Y,' 'y,' 'N,' or 'n.' In fact the program seems to be doing the opposite of what I want it to no matter how the user answers that question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int MAX_NUM = 101;
    char name[MAX_NUM];
    char response;
    char nameCorrect = 'n';
    double total = 0;

    do{

        do{
            cout << "Please enter name: ";
            cin >> name;
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            cout << "It looks like you entered " << name
                << ". Is this correct? (Y/N) " << endl;
            cin >> nameCorrect;
            while (nameCorrect != 'y' & nameCorrect != 'Y'  & nameCorrect != 'n' & nameCorrect != 'N')
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(200, '\n');
                cout << '\n' << "If " << name <<
                    " is what you are trying to enter, "
                    << "please enter Y." << '\n'
                    << "If " << name << " is not correct, plese enter N."
                    << '\n' << "(Y/N): ";
                cin >> nameCorrect;

            }

        } while (nameCorrect == 'n' || nameCorrect == 'N');


        cout << "Would you like to enter another name? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> response;

        if (response != 'y' & response != 'Y' & response != 'n' & response != 'N');
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(200, '\n');
            cout << '\n' << "If you would like to enter another name Y."
                << '\n' << "If you are finished, please enter N. " << '\n' << "(Y/N): ";
            cin >> response;

        }


    } while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use && instead in your while loop .

Comment: while `&&` is clearer and allows short circuiting - it should work as desired since the bools are converted to 1 or 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this code:

```
if (response != 'y' & response != 'Y' & response != 'n' & response != 'N');
```

Remove the `;` at the end

the `;` is what the `if` is conditionally executing and the block below will always run.

Comment: You should also wrap each condition in a pair of parenthesis: `if ((response != 'y') & (response != 'Y') & (response != 'n') & (response != 'N'))`

Comment: and use logicals, && - but that won't change the behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
if (response != 'y' & response != 'Y' & response != 'n' & response != 'N');
```

`&` is the bitwise operator in C/C++, use `&&` for boolean comparisons. Also, the semicolon at the end means you want the `if` to have exactly no effect, and always execute the following code block no matter the outcome of this line.

Comment: I finally typed faster than somebody else :)